# how to show next list item in unordered list

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I've a unordered list, like this:

menu 1

menu 2

menu 3

menu 4

→

When I click on last `li` that contains an arrow, the next li's should appear one after one.

menu 1 →
menu 1 menu 2 →
menu 1 menu 2 menu 3 →
my jQuery cod is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.nav li:first, .nav li:last').css('display','inline-block');
  $('.nav .arrow').click(function(){
    var current = $('.nav li').first();
    if($(current).is(':visible')){
      current.next().css('display','inline-block');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.nav li:last').css('display','inline-block');
    $('.nav .arrow').click(function(){
        $(this).prevAll("ul li").css("display", "inline-block");
    }); 
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/6BU4E/1/

Answer (score 0):

I've created a sample code for this

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#arrow").click(function () {
            var count = $(".menuList").length;
            var newItem = $('<li/>', { "class": "menuList", html: "menu" + count + 1 });
            $("#menu").append(newItem);

        });
    });


</script>

<body>
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="menuList">menu1</li>
</ul>
<span id="arrow">-></span>
</body>
```